# Jquery : If select has option 1 show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, show-hide

I have a dynamically created drop down and if the option "Other" is in that drop down i want to show div `#optionalmess`

```html
<select class="VariationSelect" style="width: 95px;">
    <option value="">Select Size</option>
    <option value="1">Example</option
    <option value="21">Other</option>
</select>
```

If `.variationselect` contains the option "Other" (or value="21") show `#optionalmess`

If "other" (value="21") is not in the drop down, I want to hide `#optionalmess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), in conjunction with [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for this:

```
$('#optionalmess').toggle(
    $(".VariationSelect option:contains('Other')").length > 0 
);
```

Comment: i tried something similar to this i think it was more like if .variationselect option:contans('Other')   show optionalmess  but you have the toggle optionalmess on top... this one worked i was so close to this but couldn't waste anymore time trying to figure it out.. thanks

Comment: This isn't really a safe approach, since anything containing "Option" in its text will also match here.

Comment: @Nick Craver but only in the variationselect options... i get what youre saying but in my case this works fine, the only other options are going to be numbers

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for the hide/show with a condition, like this:

```
$("#optionalmess").toggle($(".VariationSelect option[value=21]").length>0);
```

This looks for any `<option>` with a value of 21 under `.VariationSelect` and checks the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to see if any elements matched that selector.

Comment: hmm not quite i dont want to show when the option is selected i want to show when the option is available

Comment: too bad i had to refresh the page to see the update... this one is similar to the one i used below.. sorry but Dexter FTW

Comment: @Alex - note my comment on his answer, it's not safe to use `:contains()` in these cases, since it's a substring.  Also, it's much more expensive for that inexact match,