# Showing and Hiding Part of a form (div?) on drop down menu selection

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have a query i hope you can help with, i have searched but cant find an answer to my exact question.

I have a drop down (select) menu  that depending on selection needs to show 2 extra fields
Every other question I have seen depends on different selections showing different fields.

```
<select  id="idhere" name="namehere" title="Mortgage Type">

<option value="First Time Buyer">First Time Buyer</option> 
<option value="Moving Home">Moving Home</option>
<option value="Remortgage">Remortgage</option>
<option value="Buy To Let Purchase">Buy To Let Purchase</option>
<option value="Buy To Let Remortgage">Buy To Let Remortgage</option>
</select>
```

The following need to show 2 extra form fields (held within a div below)

```
First Time Buyer
Moving Home
Buy To Let Purchase
```

These both do not need to show the extra fields

```
Remortgage
Buy To Let Remortgage
```

Finally The Extra Fields are:

```
<p>Have You Found A Property</p>
<input  id="foundpropery" type="checkbox" value="0" />
<br />
<br />

<p>Have You Made An Offer</p>
<input  id="foundproperty" type="checkbox" value="0" />
```

Using javascript? How do i show the extra fields depending on selection

In advance thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be a starting point for what you're trying to do, you use the div's "display" property to show/hide it depending on what's selected in the dropdown:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle() {
var e = document.getElementById("selectList");
var strMortgageType = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var divToHide1 = document.getElementById("foundproperty");
var divToHide2 = document.getElementById("madeoffer");
if(strMortgageType == "Remortgage" || strMortgageType == "BuyToLetRemortgage")
{
divToHide1.style.display = "none";
divToHide2.style.display = "none";
}
else
{
divToHide1.style.display = "block";
divToHide2.style.display = "block";
}
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select  id="selectList" name="namehere" title="Mortgage Type" onchange="toggle()">
<option value="FirstTimeBuyer">First Time Buyer</option> 
<option value="MovingHome">Moving Home</option>
<option value="Remortgage">Remortgage</option>
<option value="BuyToLetPurchase">Buy To Let Purchase</option>
<option value="BuyToLetRemortgage">Buy To Let Remortgage</option>
</select>
<div id="foundproperty">
<p>Have You Found A Property</p>
<input  id="foundpropery" type="checkbox" value="0" />
<br />
<br />
</div>
<div id="madeoffer">
<p>Have You Made An Offer</p>
<input  id="madeofferInput" type="checkbox" value="0" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you're using jquery, this post may be helpful:

[Jquery : If select has option 1 show div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160234/jquery-if-select-has-option-1-show-div)